# UICollectionView layout for each section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I need to set one of my `UICollectionView` sections to scroll horizontally, where the rest of the `UICollectionView` scrolls vertically.

For example: **SECTION 1** below should scroll left to right, where the entire `UICollectionView` scrolls up and down.

```
|               |   ^
| [ SECTION 0 ] |    
|               |   |
| [   <-->    ] |   |
| [ SECTION 1 ] |   |
| [   <-->    ] |   |
|               |   |
| [ SECTION 2 ] |
|               |   ˅
```

You cannot nest a new `UICollectionView` inside of a `UICollectionViewCell`, so that's out of the question. I also do not want to use a `UITableView` AND a `UICollectionView` since I need most of the other sections to be grid layouts.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using scrollview as main view and add section 0 ,1, 2(collection view) in scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Take the **Tableview** which will **scroll** **vertically** then in UITablviewCell take UIView (this is done for making non conflicting delegates of collectionview and tableview),With **UIView** take **UICollectionview** and make it **scroll** **horizontally**.Thus you can achieve this easily.

> UITableView->UITbaleviewCell->In Tableviewcell a UIView->then
>   UICollectionview->UICollectionviewCell

Comment: Not looking to use a tableview (cut down on delegate code). I am thinking instead of just building UIViews for this section and place them horizontally on a scrollview. Just might work.

Comment: Yes that can be the solution also,but still you have to manage the delegates of scrollview.The approach you can follow is to customizing collectionviewlayout

Comment: I was thinking of layout, but not sure atm how to set a custom layout for each section of a collection view ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So you have two alternate solutions,use that...:P

Answer (score 0):

This is easier than it sounds (obviously) but there are two ways to do this.

1. Forget Section 1, instead make that content the Section Header which will contain a UIScrollView that will scroll horizontally. Then add your content there and set the contentSize for that scrollview to the size of the content and you're done. Set tapGestureRecognizers for any items that need to respond within the scrollview.
2. Make Section 1 a single cell that contains a UIScrollView just like version 1 above.

This is a nice display, I did this recently in a proof of concept that has since been trashed or I'd be able to post some code for you.